# Why can't I execute the stored procedure? (OracleException was caught)

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, ora-06550

This is code to connect to an Oracle database. It fails at the last line: dbDataAdapter.Fill(dtResult);

```
private object Execute(CommandType commandType, Common.DATA.SqlCommonExecutionType sqlCommonExecutionType, DbCommand dbCommand)

dbc = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
dbc.CommandType = commandType;
dbc.CommandText = dbCommand.CommandText;
dbc.CommandTimeout = 3600;

if (dbc.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   dbc.Connection.Open();

DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
DbDataAdapter dbDataAdapter = dbProviderFactory.CreateDataAdapter();
dbDataAdapter.SelectCommand = dbc;
dbDataAdapter.Fill(dtResult);
```

The error is "OracleRxception was caught:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'RESETUNFINISHEDJOBS' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I have access to the database through Oracle SQL*Plus. Why am I getting this error? Is the stored procedure missing on the database side or is it my code? Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: How about the SQL code? At least up until line 1, col 7

Comment: OracleRxception ==> OracleException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to define `schema.package.storedprocedure` (or `schema.table`) in your commandtext

Instead of:

```
select * from table
```

Use:

```
select * from schema.table
```

... and the same applies for functions/stored procedures

If your commandText contains just the stored procedure:

```
storedprocedurename
```

Try:

```
schema.package.storedprocedurename
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you may want to use public synonyms.  Its usually a better approach to create public synonyms for an object rather than explicitly using the owner/schema approach.  The user of these objects shouldn't need worry about schema.someObject notation with this approach.

Comment: Public synonyms can make it difficult to deal with multiple applications using the same database, since it is possible to have collisions in the public name space. I would prefer that appications be kept to their own schemas and the calling applications know their schema name instead of polluting the public name space.

Comment: Assuming you have any decent level of change control into the production db environments (ie, devs not creating/replacing synonyms themselves), synonyms don't pollute anything.  They can be helpful in various situations, but of course not entirely necessary.

Comment: The problem is that developers on one application may create a table called ADDRESSES not knowing that developers on another application are doing exactly the same thing. Or worse, the applications may be third-party where you don't control any of the source. Better to use private synonyms and a ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA